# Does BIND 9.9 show wrong number of ADDITIONAL SECTION?

Tags: dns, named, dig

I use BIND 9.9.4 and see the following issue.

The dig command shows us there is 2 records in the ADDITIONAL section:

```
ADDITIONAL: 2
```

But it only shows us 1 record actually in the response:

```
;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
 dns1.example.net.  3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Example:
From this link: https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00711/0/In-line-Signing-With-NSEC3-in-BIND-9.9-A-Walk-through.html#informer

```
root:/etc/namedb/keys# dig @127.0.0.1 foo.example.net any

  ; <<>> DiG 9.9.1-P1 <<>> @127.0.0.1 foo.example.net any
  ; (1 server found)
  ;; global options: +cmd
  ;; Got answer:
  ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20991
  ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2

  ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
  ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
  ;; QUESTION SECTION:
  ;foo.example.net.     IN  ANY

  ;; ANSWER SECTION:
  foo.example.net.  3600    IN  A   192.168.10.10

  ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
  example.net.      86400   IN  NS  dns1.example.net.

  ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
  dns1.example.net. 3600    IN  A   127.0.0.1

  ;; Query time: 0 msec
  ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
  ;; WHEN: Mon Jun 11 16:34:26 2012
  ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 95
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not technically a bug, but confusing presentation. In 9.9, dig started turning on EDNS(0) by default, so the responses come back with an OPT record in the additional section.  OPT doesn't have a defined text output format, so it isn't printed as a record; the only way you can tell it's there is to look for where it says "OPT PSEUDOSECTION" up near the top. But it *is* an extra record in the additional section, so the counts you see are correct.

If you use "dig +edns=0" in 9.8 or "dig +noedns" in 9.9, the counts will match.

Comment: I think BIND 9.9 need to improve this presentation.